# MySQL Count and sort rows

Tags: mysql, sorting, count

What is the best way to count and sort a column of data in mysql and output the results as a html list?

Example Data:

```
**Type**
Train
Car
Car
Car
Bus
Bus
```

Output should be sorted with largest count item first:

```
 - car(3)
 - bus(2)
 - train (1)
```

Also, is this bad practice to do on large table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select type, count(*) from vehicles group by type order by count(*) desc
```

In regards to:

> Also, is this bad practice to do on large table?

It depends on your table engine. MyISAM is very fast with aggregate functions like `count(*)`. However, InnoDB has to scan the table and count every time. So I would not recommend `count(*)`ing a large InnoDB table. Instead you could store a "count" variable in a meta table and update it on inserts/updates only.

Answer (score 3):

```
select type, COUNT(*) from data group by type
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this query:**

```
select t.type, count(t.type) as typecount from type as t group by type order by typecount desc
```

Hope help this query...!!